# profile python script in visual studio when it's calling to an exe file within python script

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a python script which iterates over different files and gives each of them (files) as an input to the executable of my application (my application is in C++). 
I would like to profile my application for each of the input file.

I am wondering if it is possible to use Visual Studio 2013 profiling feature.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know Visual Studio 2013 profiling feature. Do you want to profile **cpu**, **memory**, both? other?

Comment: Both, but more interested in memory profiling.

Comment: For memory profiling, I tried [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler), you need to install [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) first.

Comment: Thanks, but memory_profiler, profiling python script. However I am interested a deeper investigation. I would like to profile the executable.

Comment: I think `memory_profiler` gives you a cumulation of Python + subprocess. No sure, so…